# Drupal 7 WYSIWYG module with CKeditor library stripping form and input HTML tags when inserted into a block

Tags: 7, blocks, wysiwyg

I'm wanting to add some code snippets from MailChimp. We are using the WYSIWYG module (7.x-2.5) with the CKeditor library version (4.9.2.9). When I add the code to a block it is stripping out when rendered onto the page.

I want to add form, input and label HTML tags but these are being stripped out. What can you advise to get this form showing inside a block? We have this technique working on another site so I know it is possible.

Comment: Please share more info, what is your text format, what is the text filters that are used, and what are the allowed tags?

Comment: I do not see an option to change the text format used within blocks. I have created a Full HTML text format but I think the default is 'CKEditor profile for Filtered HTML' that allows - 'p,h3,div,form,input,label' This was found inside the content authoring section of Drupal 7 config

Comment: Is this block created by a contributed module, or a "custom block" you added by going to Structure >> Blocks and clicking "Add block"? If a custom block, then what do you see directly under the "Block body" textarea field? There should be a select box to change the "Text format", and information about what HTML tags are allowed for that format, if any (unless the format is "Full HTML"). Go to Configuration >> Content Authoring >> Text Formats, to see what formats are enabled and which roles can use them. Configuration >> Content Authoring >> Wysiwyg Profiles to assign an editor to a format.